# I am not able to set up the recuiting app in salesforce, Even after package is installed in saleforce

Tags: appexchange

[image]

In the installed packages it is showing Recruiting app details, But in App launcher or any other organizations the Recruitment app is not visible.
How to set up the recruitment app, please help on this.

Comment: Check weather you have the right permissions? Check weather the package have any permission set?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are following (or basing yourself) on a trailhead?
Best to continue the configuration by following this follow-up one
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/customize-the-ui-for-a-recruiting-app

Comment: In this article also it is mentioned that, Before you can do this project, you must complete the Build a Data Model for a Recruiting App project. for this task only i installed recruiting app, but i am not able to use that application for first task.